# Group delay plot of a Moving average filter

Tags: matlab, filter-design, moving-average, group-delay

I am implementing the moving average filter in Matlab. Using fvtool on this filter, gave the following output curve, is this group delay curve correct?

[image: Figure 1]

Edit:

1. My confusion is regarding the values of the delay output as well as the constant nature of the curve.

I implemented the filter using 'FilterDesigner' tool in matlab
(In which, filter dimensions can be specified in the GUI, which then handles the code itself) Attaching a screenshot of the tool window with filter parameters.

[image]

> After which I exported this filter as an object called 'Hd'

To plot the filter, I did -

```
fvtool(Hd)
```

Which resulted in the curve above (figure 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have added to your question why you doubt the correctness of those numbers. Anyway, the group delay of a moving average is indeed constant. It's just the parameter 'window size' that is off by one. The window size $N$ is the number of taps of the moving average filter, and the group delay is related to the window size by

$$\tau_g=\frac{N-1}{2}$$

However, in your plot, the group delay is half of the window size, so I expect that what is called 'window size' actually equals $N-1$, i.e., the number of taps minus $1$.

Comment: (I'm sorry, I'm a total beginner and this was needed to be done as a part of a bigger project) While designing the filter, I definitely set the window sizes to be 5,10,13 and 15 and I don't know why its doing N/2 instead of N-1/2. Any inputs on how I can resolve this? edit: Is is possible that while specifying the window size in Matlab for this, it is automatically up-scaling the window size to +1 i.e. 5 to 6? hence giving 6-1/2=2.5

Comment: @varungupta: You could add your code to the question. Then it's easier to know what's going on.

Comment: Added the Matlab implementations as suggested.

Comment: @varungupta: It says "Filter order: 15", which means that the filter length = order+1=16, and the corresponding group delay is 15/2=7.5. 'Filter order' shouldn't be the same as 'window size', but window size = filter order + 1.

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much your help :)